# PyroCMS Add a page using script

Tags: javascript, html, json, pyrocms

I'm trying to create a website with a search box. When a user searches using keywords, I'd like to open a new page with the search results (ideally with an optimized URL). --> The search results are populated from AJAX results in JSON format.

I've considered using PyroCMS or Wordpress, and I know of Wordpress' REST API that will allow me to create new pages dynamically. Does PyroCMS have something similar? I'm brand new to Pyro, so I was hoping someone could help me out here. I don't mind using some PHP along the way but I'd love to make it work with HTML, JS/JQuery/JSON Responses etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Pyro is a native Laravel system so you can do a whole lot with it including REST APIs whether we have an addon for it or not. We DO have an API module that makes REST APIs super easy but for a simple JSON search return I would just write your own controller and search with Pyro/Laravel's included Scout: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you very much! I'm still in the planning phase but it seems like Pyro might work for me. I was wondering if you could give me an idea of how simple it is to use custom code with PyroCMS? Would it be best to install it on my desktop and work with that environment, periodically pushing code to my live site?